# Frequent write errors to new SSD - Faulty hardware or configuration issue?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, pci-express, nvme

I replaced the primary boot drive (SSD) on my Alienware 17 R4 a few months ago after it died on me. Since then, my computer will spontaneously just stop fulfilling commands, and eventually grind to a halt for ~30 seconds at a time.

**For context:**

```
Old SSD: SK hynix (OEM), PCIe Gen3 x 4, PC300 NVMe - 256GB  
New SSD: Samsung 970 EVO Plus, NVMe M.2 - 1TB
```

I looked in Event Viewer and there are a bunch of warnings & errors referencing the new drive. The common theme is, "An IO took more than 30000 ms to complete."

Yesterday, I downloaded Samsung Magician hoping it could to a diagnostic. It didn't recognize the drive at all! After some googling, I learned that switching the SATA mode to AHCI in the BIOS resolves this problem, so I did, and sure enough, Samsung Magician then recognized the drive. That prompted a driver and firmware update. At that point, I thought I was in the clear. ….NOPE!

The same thing is happening today, but with a fun little twist. Instead of recovering after ~30 seconds, my computer freezes indefinitely.

One thing that seems a little concerning is this reference to RAID in the StorPort 549 errors, considering I changed the SATA mode to AHCI…

```
An IO took more than 30000 ms to complete:

           Process Id: 1972
           Process name: svchost.exe
           File name: \Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Storage-StorporttrueOperational.evtx
           File offset: 1445888
           IO Type: Write: NonPaging, Cached, Sync
           IO Size: 29008 bytes
           8 cluster(s) starting at cluster 14586264
           Latency: 180738 ms

           Volume Id: {c1a030b9-df67-46f7-a82d-3f96a84e0463}
           Volume name: C:
           Is boot volume: true

           Device GUID: {38b3266b-0b21-6038-b931-ae24f170993a}
           Device manufacturer: 
           Device model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
           Device revision: 3B2QEXM7
           Device serial number: 0025_3858_1151_5965.
           Bus type: RAID

           Adapter serial number:
```

Anyone know what could be causing this? I can still exchange the drive for a new one if it's defective, but I'd really like to avoid reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Reseat it and make sure it's screwed down properly and not loose?

Comment: The reference to RAID likely has nothing to do with your problem.  Did you buy the Samsung drive new or used?  *I asked this question due to the shortage of drives.*

Comment: @Ramhound I bought it new.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the SMART data of the disk to see if the firmware is reporting
any serious errors. If such errors are listed, then replace the disk.
If in doubt, you can add the SMART report to your post.

You could also install the NVMe driver from
[Samsung](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/970evoplus/),
if not already installed.
There is not much more that you can do software-wise.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. No issues reported in the SMART data. I did just install the NVMe driver from Samsung a couple days ago (the driver update I mentioned).

Comment: You did everything that is possible. I suggest to get in touch with Samsung Support, and if necessary then replace the disk. The Samsung 970 EVO Plus is a very good disk and should work without any problem (unless it has some compatibility issue with your motherboard). I suppose that BIOS and all drivers relating to the motherboard are up to date?

Comment: Yep, all BIOS & motherboard drivers are up to date. I switched the SATA mode back to RAID, since I much prefer when it freezes and eventually recovers to it freezing and needing a hard reset. One thing that's kind of interesting... When SATA mode is set to RAID, the drive is recognized by my Intel Rapid Storage Tech. utility and NOT by Samsung Magician. When SATA mode is set to AHCI, it's the other way around.

Comment: RAID is the more comprehensive mode. I would prefer Intel Rapid Storage Tech to work, rather than the older Samsung Magician.

Comment: So at this point, if you were me, would you exchange the drive for a new one?

Comment: I always exchange/return any drive that doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).